# Trying to understand a web application deployed to glassfish worked but not in weblogic server

Tags: ant, glassfish, weblogic

I downloaded sample web application (OES MAPI example) from Oracle in order to understand what it does. From the readme file, it instructs me that it is designed to run under Weblogic server and asks me to modify existing ant build script to build/deploy it.

Not having Weblogic server in my local box and not knowing much about ant script, I decided to deploy it into glassfish server b/c I have netbeans IDE which comes with ant plugin + glassfish server. I thought if I create new web project and copy/paste existing java and jsp files into it from the sample app then I don't have to worry about modifying existing ant build script but simply build war file by clicking "Clean and Build" from the project then deploy it and test it. It worked fine.

Later, I was told to deploy the war file to remote Weblogic server. So I did it. From admin console, its status looks good. However when I accessed the resource, "Error 404 Not Found From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1: 10.4.5 404 Not Found".

I would like to know why it worked in glassfish but not in Weblogic server.

update:

It was my fault. I realized that I deployed oes sample app (resource) to oes manged nodes 1 and 2 instead of admin server. However I was requesting the resource from the admin server address instead of managed node servers. No wonder http 404 error message was returned. I am sorry if I wasted others' time for this matter.

Comment: What kind of resource? Rest ? Servlet? Please give more details about your war content.

Comment: forgive me. The resource is servlet/JSP.